# What's the principle of such application that can stream TV?

Tags: video-streaming, television

One of their product called [**Live2Phone Personal TV**](http://live2phone.com/) attracts me lot,

anyone knows how it's implemented ? What devices does it require to work?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Live2Phone](http://live2phone.com/) website:

> It includes a server application component installable on a personal computer and a client application (mobile viewer), installable on a S60 3rd   Edition mobile phone. The server connects to a TV Tuner hardware and offers full control upon the streaming process. You can watch any TV channel available at home or an external video source for example a DVD player.

It appears you would need a computer with a TV tuner card.

The video from the computer is transmitted over the Internet through a [streaming server](http://www.mediacollege.com/video/streaming/server.html) at Live2Phone to your mobile phone.

The server application component on your computer allows you to change channels on the TV tuner from the mobile phone.